# Flask Pymongo Insert returns a collection object rather than _id

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-pymongo

I'm just getting started with Flask_Pymongo (and pymongo in general). I wrote a simple test route that successfully inserts to my mongo db, however the return is not as expected. If I'm not mistaken pymongo should return the `_id` field if I call inserted_id on the return. Seems like Flask_Pymongo is returning a collection object however:

```
@main.route('/')
def index():
    user_collection = mongo.db.users
    user_collection.insert_one({'name': 'Jack Black'})
    print(user_collection.inserted_id)
    return "<H2>Added a user!</H2>"
```

Returned object:

```
Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=False), 'example'), 'users.inserted_id')
```

The insert operation is successful otherwise and I see the new document with _id. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to get `_id` is :

```
id = user_collection.insert_one({'name': 'Jack Black'}).inserted_id
print(id)

(Or)

userDoc = user_collection.insert_one({'name': 'Jack Black'})
print(userDoc.inserted_id)
```

**Ref :** [pymongo-insert_one](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one)